# How does std::array initializer work for char's?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

I'm not sure how the following code works. I thought you had to do `{'h', 'e' ...etc...}` but it seems to work fine. On the other hand if you do `std::array<const char*` it only adds one element to the array. Are there special rules for string literal initialization?

```
std::array<char, strlen("hello world!") + 1> s = {"hello world!"};
for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << s[i];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class `std::array` is an aggregate. In this statement:

```
std::array<char, strlen("hello world!") + 1> s = {"hello world!"};
```

list initialization is used. As the first and only element of this instantiation of the class `std::array` is a character array it may be initialized with string literals.

It would be more correctly to use `sizeof` operator instead of function `strlen`:

```
std::array<char, sizeof( "hello world!" )> s = {"hello world!"};
```

Also you could write

```
std::array<char, sizeof( "hello world!" )> s = { { "hello world!" } };
```

because the character array in turn is an aggregate.

According to the C++ Standard

[8.5.2 Character arrays [dcl.init.string]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.string)

> 1 An array of narrow character type (3.9.1), `char16_t` array, `char32_t`
>   array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow string literal,
>   `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string literal, or wide string
>   literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal
>   enclosed in braces (2.14.5). Successive characters of the value of the
>   string literal initialize the elements of the array.
>
> [ Example:

```
char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of achieving this

```
// GOAL
std::array<char, sizeof("Hello")> myarray = {"Hello"};
```

ie. **initializing std::array with a string literal** (yes, it used a macro)

```
// SOLUTION
#define STD_CHAR_ARRAY_INIT(arrayname, string_literal) /*std::array*/<char, sizeof(string_literal)> arrayname = {string_literal}
std::array STD_CHAR_ARRAY_INIT(myarray, "Hello");
```

Here's some test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;

template<typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& os, array<T, N> arr)
{
  {
    size_t cnt = 0;
    char strchar[2] = "x";
    for (const T& c : arr) {
      strchar[0] = c;
      os << "arr[" << cnt << "] = '" << (c == '\0' ? "\\0" :  strchar /*string(1, c)*/  ) << "'\n"
         << '.' << c << '.' << '\n';
      ++cnt;
    }
  }
  return os;
}


#define STD_CHAR_ARRAY_INIT(arrayname, string_literal) /*std::array*/<char, sizeof(string_literal)> arrayname = {string_literal}

int main()
{
  std::array STD_CHAR_ARRAY_INIT(myarray, "Hello");
  cout << myarray << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```